# Delegate method does not get called - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

AddBillViewController.h:

```
@protocol AddBillDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addBillViewControllerDidAddOneBill;

@end

@interface AddBillViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic)id <AddBillDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

AddBillViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)AddBill:(id)sender {

    [self.delegate addBillViewControllerDidAddOneBill];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

HomeViewController.m:

```
@interface HomeViewController () <AddBillDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)AddBillViewController *abVC;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.abVC = [[AddBillViewController alloc] init];
    self.abVC.delegate = self;
}

- (void)addBillViewControllerDidAddOneBill {
    NSLog(@"Added a bill.");
}

@end
```

As you can see, there is button in AddBillViewController, when the button is pressed, `addBill` method will be called, then the delegate method `addBillViewControllerDidAddOneBill` in HomeViewController should be called, however in fact, it doesn't.

Comment: Try @synthesize abVC; & call abVC without self.

Comment: @BC_Dilum why do you think it should help?

Comment: @BC_Dilum: Why` @synthesize` ?

Comment: The code adduced is absolutely correct and must work. It is probably some simple mistake somewhere else

Comment: What is the order of your View Controller presentation ? And how it is presented ?

Comment: @MidhunMP AddBillViewController is next to HomeViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not getting the reference right here in this line

```
self.abVC = [[AddBillViewController alloc] init];
```

If you are performing a segue, like the AddBillViewController is your next controller, set delegate in performSegue: function

like

```
AddBillViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
[vc setDelegate:self];
```